# Unable to customize Pivot Table CSS in Superset

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, apache-superset

I would like to customize the CSS of the pivot table, using the dashboard-chart-id is not good, because it references a way bigger area than the actual table, I tried to inspect the HTML of the dashboard and directly edited it in the Firefox inspector and I can edit the things I want to like simply put background-colour here:
`.css-7tmzyl table.pvtTable { position: relative; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; margin: 4px; border-collapse: separate; font-family: "Inter", Helvetica, Arial; line-height: 1.4; background-color: brown !important; }`

However, placing the background-colour part in the CSS editor does nothing.

I'm kind of new to CSS (I used it with JS in the past, however with the framework we used that was very straightforward), however, I checked the places I could, tried to reference different parts of the code and also tried directly just reference the class or the table or putting "a." before class. The result is that nothing happens, however when I use the dashboard chart-id I can edit it, but that's too big